# Is it easy to see that this function is subharmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, riemann-surfaces

I would like to know if the function $$\frac{1}{(1+\vert z\vert^2)^2}$$ is subharmonic on $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{P}^1-\{\infty\}$.

**Motivation.** The Fubini-Study metric on the complex projective line $\mathbf{P}^1$ is given by $$\frac{i}{2\pi} \frac{dz \wedge d\overline{z}}{(1+\vert z\vert^2)^2} ;$$ this depends on the choice of the coordinate $z$.

I can think of two possiblities. Firstly, just an ugly computation with derivatives. Secondly, an argument using properties of the Fubini-study metric, i.e., it is a smooth positive real $(1,1)$-form.

Question. Is the above function subharmonic?

Question. If yes, then is it possible to prove this without calculating derivatives?

Comment: What's so bad about taking derivatives? Using $\Delta = 4 \partial \overline{\partial}$ and $|z|^2 = z\bar{z}$ this is a trivial exercise (two lines at most). I get $$\Delta \frac{1}{(1+|z|^2)^2} = \frac{16|z|^2 - 8}{(1+|z|^2)^4}$$ which doesn't look very positive to me (plug in $|z| \lt \sqrt{2}/2$ and $|z| \gt \sqrt{2}/2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this function is not subharmonic on the whole plane, as an easy computation can show (its $\partial \bar \partial$ equals something like $2(2|z|^2-1)/(1+|z|^2)^4$.)

As for the Fubini-Study metric, it can be viewed as the curvature form of the so-called Fubini-Study metric on the line bundle $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1)$, its local potential on $\mathbb P^1 - \{\infty\}$ is given by $\varphi(z)= \log (1+|z|^2)$, so that the metrics is $i \partial \bar \partial \varphi$, which is well-defined globally. Its local expression is then as you wrote

$$\omega_{\rm FS}=\frac{i}{2\pi} \frac{dz\wedge d\bar z}{(1+|z|^2)^2}$$

To sum up, whenever you have a positive (1,1) form $\omega$ on a manifold, then its local potentials (ie the functions $\varphi$ such that $\omega = i\partial \bar \partial \varphi$ locally) are (pluri)subharmonic functions, but you can't say anything about the term in $dz \wedge d\bar z$, except that it is positive (or in higher dimension, the terms in $dz_i \wedge d\bar z_j$ form a positive definite hermitian matrix).

Comment: I think your $\partial \bar{\partial}$ should have $2(2|z|^2 - 1)$ in the numerator (see my comment to the question).

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me understand the situation much better.

Comment: @Theo: You're perfectly right, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Subharmonic means http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic_function the value at the center of a circle is $\le$ the average value around the circle?  Try a circle centered at the origin.

Comment: The value at the origin is 1 and the average value around a circle of radius r>0 is 1/(1+r^2)^2 > 1. Nice. This is an easy way of seeing it. I do wonder though if my function is subharmonic on some small open disc centered at $z\neq 0$.  Is this true?

Comment: Theo Buehler's answer suggests that the function above is subharmonic outside the open unit disc D(0,sqrt(1/2)). Let G be the complement of D(0,sqrt(1,2)) in \C. In this case I can directly see that the function above (restricted to this G) takes its maximum on the boundary of the disc D(0,sqrt(1,2)) = boundary of G.

Comment: The computation (made by Theo in the comments, or see my answer) show that your function is subharmonic exactly in the domain $\{|z|^2>1/2\}$.