# The canonical (1,1)-form on a compact Riemann surface gives locally a subharmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, riemann-surfaces, differential-forms

Let $X$ be a compact connected Riemann surface of genus $g>0$.

We have the so called *canonical* (1,1)-form $\mu$ on $X$ defined as follows. Choose an orthonormal basis $(\omega_1,\ldots, \omega_g)$ for the space of holomorphic differentials $H^0(X,\Omega^1_X)$ with respect to the natural inner product $(\omega,\eta) \mapsto \frac{i}{2} \int_X \omega \wedge \overline{\eta}.$ Then $\mu = \frac{i}{2g} \sum_{k=1}^g \omega_k \wedge \overline{\omega_k}$. This is independent of the choice of orthonormal basis. Note that $\int_X \mu = 1$

Now, the following fact seems to be well-known.

Let $x\in X$ and let $z:U\longrightarrow B(0,1)$ be a chart at $x$, where $B(0,1)$ denotes the open unit disc in $\mathbf{C}$.

Write $\mu = i F dz d\overline{z}$ on $U\subset X$. Then, after shrinking $U$ if necessary, $F$ extends to a subharmonic function on the compactification/closure of $U$.

Does anybody know a nice reference for this?

This question is the higher genus analogue of my previous question [Is it easy to see that this function is subharmonic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46490/is-it-easy-to-see-that-this-function-is-subharmonic) In that question it was made clear that the Fubini-Study metric has this property around  $\infty$. The open $U$ being the complement of the open disc $B(0,1/2)$.

Comment: Farkas and Kra?